# How to apply BorderRadius for a Container with Stack widget?

Tags: flutter

This code is that I have tried.

```dart
Container(
  height: 250,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
  ),
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      Positioned.fill(
        child: Image.asset(
          'assets/images/background.png',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      Positioned.fill(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.35),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Center(
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: const  Text(
              'Scrollable Component at the Top',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

I tried to fix it by using `ClipRRect` widget but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

i'm trying to figure out what exactly your problem is. your possible needs will found in the following code

here are some of done work:

- making the image rounded because it's the background for the whole
  content.
- making the container which uses `ClipRRect` rounded and it's proved
  by shpe of its borders

, try to remove border property of the `BoxDeconration` of that container.

here's the code:

```
SizedBox(
        height: 250,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned.fill(
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                  child: Image.asset('images/1.jpg', fit: BoxFit.cover)
              ),
            ),
            Positioned.fill(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.35),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  // you can remove borders.
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 1),
                  // i'm setting border to show you it's rounded
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                ),
              
                child: const Text(
                  'Scrollable Component at the Top',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

here's the result:

[image]

you can remove the white borders of the container just by removing border property from `BoxDecoration.`

hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the `Container` with `ClipRRect` should work. Make sure your image fills the full height so the `ClipRRect` doesn't clip the border in the extra empty space.

```dart
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
  child: Container(
    // ...
  ),
)
```

**Result:**

[image: Screenshot]